# ReSharper won't convert functions to lambda expressions if they contain "this"

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, resharper

Resharper presents a very helpful option for callback functions that are written in conventional JavaScript to convert them to lambda expressions.

[image]

I use it all the time. However, it doesn't seem to give the option if there's a reference to `this` inside the function.

Example:

```
// ReSharper will convert this function:
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("This one gives me the option to convert!");
});

// ReSharper will NOT convert this function:
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("This one doesn't!");
    this.willConvert = false;
});

// This is what it looks like after converted
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("This one has been converted");
});
```

Is there a way to change an option in ReSharper to give this option more liberally?

Comment: The semantics of the fat arrow would change the "meaning" of `this` because `() => {}` is bound to the context of the containing method.  If it changed the method, it may break because `this` wouldn't be the function's this, it would instead be the global context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I suspect this is because it's not a clean refactoring if `this` is present. The lambda syntax changes what `this` means. In your example, the function passed to `setTimeout` has `this` set to the global object. If you convert it to an arrow function, `this` changes to be the same `this` as where the function is declared (in this particular case, that looks like the global object again, but in other cases it could be a surrounding function, etc).

If ReSharper suggested this change, it would be too easy to introduce a breaking change.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    var self = this;   
    console.log("This one doesn't!");
    self.willConvert = false;
});
```

Comment: This does not address the problem at all, and actually doesn't do anything at all. Setting `self` to `this` in the same closure that you use `self` is pointless.